# Unable to stream microphone audio to Google Speech to Text with NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am going to develop a simple web based Speech to Text project. Develop with NodeJS, ws (WebSocket), and Google's Speech to Text API.

However, I have no luck to get the transcript from Google's Speech to Text API.

Below are my server side codes (server.js):

```
ws.on('message', function (message) {
    if (typeof message === 'string') {
        if(message == "connected") {
            console.log(`Web browser connected postback.`);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (recognizeStream !== null) {
            const buffer = new Int16Array(message, 0, Math.floor(message.byteLength / 2));
            recognizeStream.write(buffer);
        }
    }
});
```

Below are my client side codes (ws.js):

```
function recorderProcess(e) {
    var floatSamples = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    const ConversionFactor = 2 ** (16 - 1) - 1;
    var floatSamples16 = Int16Array.from(floatSamples.map(n => n * ConversionFactor));
    ws.send(floatSamples16);
}

function successCallback(stream) {
    window.stream = stream;
    var audioContext = window.AudioContext;
    var context = new audioContext();
    var audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
    recorder.onaudioprocess = recorderProcess;
    audioInput.connect(recorder);
    recorder.connect(context.destination);
}
```

When I run the project, and open http://localhost/ in my browser, trying to speaking some sentences to the microphone. Unfortunately, there are no transcription returned, and no error messages returned in NodeJS console.

When I check the status in Google Cloud Console, it only display a 499 code in the dashboard.

Many thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue could be related to the stream process. Maybe some streaming process is stopped before the end of an operation. My suggestion is to review the callbacks in the JasvaScript code in order to find some “broken" promises.

Also, maybe its obvious but there is a different doc for audios than more than a minute:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize

CANCELLED - The operation was cancelled, typically by the caller.

HTTP Mapping: 499 Client Closed Request

Since the error message, this also could be related to the asynchronous and multithread features of node js.

Hope this works!